# how to make Light not go through 3DGameObjects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, light

I am creating a game where a flashlight is involved, though i have found the light source is going through walls that i have created [Example showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY0st.png)

I have found other questions like these, where the response was to put any form of bias as low as possible. which in my case still didn't work
[Bias and Normal Bias = 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24UIh.png)

is there any other reason why this is the case?

thank you

Comment: Are your walls static? I had some light bleed through well not through more at joins and some gentle nudging and making slight overlap helped along with being static.

Comment: They weren't static, I have gone and checked it for all, though I have made it also overlap the wall with the ground and I'm still getting the same results. unless there is a possible bleed between the two shapes in the prefab for the wall?

Comment: Unity have some lighting tutorials. They should help

Comment: I have found out that the reason that there are no shadows being cast is that the material's shader is diffuse, this was to allow me to easily apply a textured material though I think I just needed to set my shader back to standard

Comment: You didnt mention shadows.

Comment: though it also resolves the initial issue that I had - having light being cast through objects, and I had only released that solving this issue meant that there are shadows now showing